# UniqueConstraint for JWT token - how to?

Tags: symfony, jwt, symfony4, unique-constraint, lexikjwtauthbundle

My enviroment:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
   user_identity_field: phoneNumber
```

```
security:
   providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: ['fos_userbundle', 'app_user_provider']
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: phoneNumber
```

in App\Entity\User

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="`user`",
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *        @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="project_phoneNumber", columns={"project_id", "phone_number"})
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
```

So the problem is that phoneNumber is not unique for user any more.
Is it possible to use project_phoneNumber for user identity in jwt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you trying to do is a compound primary key.

This is a very good way to proceed at a database level.
So the way you want to do it is the good way.

Problem is that even though doctrine say that they :

> ...took good care to make sure Doctrine ORM supports as many of the composite primary key use-cases
> https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

This is in fact a real pain when you face one unsupported feature for composite primary key (example : when you want to perform a manyToMany on two entity with composed primary key...).

So what I recommend to do is to always use id as primary key even though it'll violate the [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

This is an acceptable violation... I mean not for me but there is no other way to handle it for complex entity relation.

So if you want to try your luck you may [implement a composite primary key](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities) and so remove you unique constraint which is handle by the primary key itself.

Else, just use a simple auto-incremented id and you'll be good (and so keep your unique constraint).